# Mysql GROUP BY similar fields

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, soundex

Suppose I have this table with customer orders:

```
orderid Name         Email      Address_1      Address_2  City*      Zip*
---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
1       James        j@j.com    12 Foo St                 Fooville   1001
2       Alice        a@a.com    92 Bla Road               Sville     3933
3       James        j@j.c0m    12 Foo Street             Fooville   1001
4       james king   j@j.com    12             Foo St     Fooville   1001
5       Anth         ann@h.com  12 Foo Street             Stacker    2932
6       James        j@j.com    12 American St            GiftCity   0283
```

To save postage costs (for us), it would be ideal if we could send multiple orders going to the **same person**, to the **same address** in one print slip. For this, I need a unique record for id 1, 3, 4.

The `City` and `Zip` codes cannot be entered by the user (selected from a drop down).

Ideally, I would like the following to be returned by my query:

```
orderid Name    Email      Address_1      Address_2  City*      Zip*  Count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
1       James   j@j.com    12 Foo St                 Fooville   1001  3
2       Alice   a@a.com    92 Bla Road               Sville     3933  1
5       Anth    ann@h.com  12 Foo Street             Stacker    2932  1
```

Essentially, the SQL algorithm is doing a group by on similar on the following columns: `Name`, `Email`, `concat(Address_1 and Address_2)`.

Any advice and solutions would be highly appreciated.

If there is a way to do a

```
GROUP BY similar((concat(name,email,address_1)
```

(really sorry about the hopeless pseudo-code.. just trying to get my thoughts across).

Comment: What are the rules for 'similar'? In your example 'Foo Street' is equal to 'Foo St' which is pretty much guessing.

Comment: How many orders do you have on a daily basis?  Could you do some manual review by a human viewer?  Also, you could use an address verification service that determines the Zip+4 code, and compare on the Zip+4 code instead.

Comment: If a human see's the first table, they would be able to easily draw up the second table. Is there a way to do this via a mixture of mysql functions?

Comment: @K.H good luck with inventing SkyNet then :P

Comment: I would start by getting address rectification software that converts all the addresses to a fixed format.

Comment: @mellamokb - it's a group buy site, so basically all the orders come in very quickly over a short period of time, then we just print the labels when we are shipping them out. At the moment we try our best to do a manual verification, but sometimes cheap products sell 1000's and we end up missing out hundreds of records. At the moment, we are just doing a simple group by 'email' order by address_1 and it works, but only if the user has entered their address and email address exactly the same in all the orders. Most of them just have slight errors a few characters out of place here and there.

Comment: Is there a way to do a group by (soundex(name+email+address_1+address_2) ?

Comment: `GROUP BY SOUNDEX(CONCAT(field1,field2,...))`. But you might wanna use `GROUP BY SOUNDEX(name),email,city,zip,SOUNDEX(CONCAT(address_1,addres_2))`. And that will still need human verification.

Comment: @Vatev thanks! didn't know i could do that. it definitely does improve on our existing query.

Comment: its easy can you provide table structure

Comment: You may have better luck if you have a table which stores the customer name, Then you can get the exact listing of all orders for a given customer/delivery address.

Comment: @raheelshan: it's in the original post?

Comment: @X-Zero: customers all purchase as guests..

Comment: If you mean 'guest' as 'registration not required', there are ways around this.  Specifically, log the email address, along with the name and postal address shipped to in 'regular' 'customer data' tables.  Then, if someone uses a known email address, it checks name/address for similarity, and just uses the existing one if it's 'close enough' (address canonicalization will help, and probably with postal rates too).

Comment: @X-Zero - but what if they are purchasing as gifts? Example: orderid #6 in table one.

Comment: That would be a 'new' address, with a separate entry for (postal) address, not a repetition of the 'existing' one.  Technically, the system doesn't really have a way (here) to determine which is the 'gift' address.  Shouldn't that be a different row in your results anyways?

Answer (score 1):

Well instead of discussion here is a query modify according to your requirements

```
select 
    orderid , 
    name , 
    email , 
    address_1 , 
    address_2 , 
    city , 
    zip , 
    count(orderid) 
from test 
group by name
order by orderid
```

Brings out this

```
    Name        Email       Address_1    Address_2  City        Zip Count
1   James       j@j.com     12 Foo St           Fooville        1001    3
2   Alice       a@a.com     92 Bla Road         Sville          3933    1
4   James King  j@j.com     12 Foo St           Fooville        1001    1
5   Anth        ann@h.com   12 Foo St           Stacker         2932    1
```